# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'piece' of null event click

Tags: angular7

```
             <li
                *ngIf ="element.backSoon === '0'" 
                class="size-list-element"
                role="option"
                (click)="sizeSelected($event, element)">
                    <a href="#" class="size-list-element-link">
                            {{element.name}}

                    </a>
                </li>
```

Tengo un click en el elemento li y un enlace dentro. Mi problema es que deseo hacer un event.stopPropagation() y event.preventDefault() en su función pero salta el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el motivo es al pasar ese event.

```
public sizeSelected(productSize: ProductSize, event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    const elementSize: ProductStatus = {
        sku: productSize.sku,
        availability: productSize.availability,
        backSoon: productSize.backSoon
    }
    if ( productSize.availability === 'out_of_stock' ) {

        this.selectionTxt = 'Ver tallas';
        this.selectedSize.emit(elementSize);

    } else {

        this.selectionTxt = productSize.name || 'Ver tallas';
        this.selectedSize.emit(elementSize);
    }
    this.visibleList = false;
}
```

Comment: Si añades el código de la implementación de `sizeSelected()` se verá más claro el problema, aunque intuyo qué está pasando, el código del método ayudará a dar una respuesta más certera.

Answer (score 0):

El problema "parece" claro, tienes los parámetros al reves:

```
(click)="sizeSelected($event, element)">
```

Debería ser:

```
(click)="sizeSelected(element, $event)">
```

Sin embargo, el mensaje de error no me encaja muy bien, es posible que además esté pasado otra cosa adicionalmente, quizás en el código de la propia directiva RenderLinks que aparece en las trazas, donde se accede al atributo `.piece`